# Laravel - Auth::attempt not working with sha512

Tags: php, laravel

Let me show you exact code:

```
$credentials = array(
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => hash('sha512', $request->password)
);
```

Now this returns `true`:

```
User::where($credentials)->exists()
```

However this returns `false`:

```
Auth::attempt($credentials)
```

I am using sha512 to store my passwords. Why `Auth::attempt` returns false ?

Comment: `Auth::attempt` expects the plain password, not a hash.

Comment: @tkausl I tried that first. Even with plain it does not work sir.

Comment: I guess it does not work because you're using SHA512 instead of the algorithm laravel uses.

Comment: You would have to write your own authentication provider. Don't do it, just use Laravel's built-in hashing. SHA-512 has been considered insecure for a few years now.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel `Hash` facade provides secure [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) and [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) hashing for storing user passwords.

But, you can create you custom hash like this :

```
$user = User::where([
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => hash('sha512', $request->password)
])->first();

if($user){
    Auth::login($user);
}
```

> Bcrypt is a great choice for hashing passwords because its "work factor" is adjustable, which means that the time it takes to generate a hash can be increased as hardware power increases. When hashing passwords, slow is good. The longer an algorithm takes to hash a password, the longer it takes malicious users to generate "rainbow tables" of all possible string hash values that may be used in brute force attacks against applications.